# how to remove img tag from html

Tags: jquery, html

This is What I have when I do quick watch, In the innerHtml

```
   <img style="width: 100%; height: 320px;" src="img/banner03.jpg">
   <div class="bjqs-caption">
       Automatically generated caption3
   </div>
```

But What I want in the innerHTML as :

```
    <div class="bjqs-caption">
         Automatically generated caption3
    </div>
```

How will as remove img tag from the innerHTML

Comment: do you want to remove the `img` or image and the parent div

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.bjqs-caption').prev('img').remove()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div img').remove();
});
```

This will delete all images in every div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bjqs-caption').siblings('img').remove();
});
```

This will remove all images that are siblings of `.bjqs-caption`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('img').remove();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:[empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.bjqs-caption').prev('img').empty();
})
```